# Mean differences between a population and its subsamples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, two-sample

We would like to perform a statistical test to assess that a subsample of a global population has significantly a different mean than the global population.
In this context, we are convinced that a statistical test where the null hypothesis H_0 is {means are equal} is what we would like to perform.

To know more about our samples:

- the whole population contains more than 60000 values, it passed Gaussian testing and can be considered Gaussian.
- the subpopulation contains less than 1000 samples. Based on some criteria that we will not discuss here this subpopulation is varying, but most of the time it can also be considered Gaussian. Let us assume that this subpopulation is Gaussian.

For now on, we did not change the variances of our samples but we could divide the global population results by its standard deviation in order to achieve normalization.

We hesitate between the three following tests:

- One sample T-Test.
- Two sample T-Test.

  We have absolutely no knowledge that our subpopulation and the global population have equal variance. Practice showed that they have not. However, "equal variances" is one of the t-Tests assumptions see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).
- [Welsh Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) 
  Welsh Tests looks more appropriate but the independence of the sample is not verified as well. The subpopulation and globalpopulation are by definition dependent. Should we remove our subpopulation from the global population in order to have non overlapping samples?

Among these three tests which one is recommended? Is there a better test in the litterature for what we are trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not think it is an exact duplicate previous question does not mention the Welsh Tests as a possible candidate.